# Facebook feed dialog sample code in C# using api

Tags: facebook, dialog, feed

I have written an application which writes on my friend's timeline a message. With February 2013 new policy I need to display the feed dialog in order to do so. 
Is there any sample code available to understand how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

go to the fallowing link,it may help you.

http://webmodelling.com/webbits/socialmedia/facebook-api.aspx?ml-d-uepp=1

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.